# proof involving eigenvalues and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I think a similar question has been asked for this proof but going in the opposite direction.

Question:

Let $A$ be a $n*n$ real matrix. Let $λ ∈ \mathbb{R}$ such that $λ^2$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A^2$. Prove that $λ$ or $−λ$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$.

I know I will using the equation $Ax=λx$ but can't quite see how to manipulate it. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Because $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue $\mathrm{Ker}(A^2 - \lambda) \neq 0$

Therefore
$\mathrm{Ker}((A + \lambda)(A-\lambda)) \neq 0$

Therefore $\mathrm{Ker}(A + \lambda) \neq 0$ or $\mathrm{Ker}(A-\lambda) \neq 0$

From that proof you can construct eigenvector for $A$ from $x$ s.t. $A^2 x = \lambda ^2$

$(A + \lambda)(A-\lambda)x = 0$

Therefore either $(A-\lambda)x = 0$ or
$$(A-\lambda)x\neq0 \text{ and } (A+\lambda)((A-\lambda)x) = 0$$

Therefore either $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with an eigenvector $x$ or $(A-\lambda)x$ respectively.